# PHP MySQL result - unnecessary use of foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, resultset

I use this method to access my MySQL database:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE unum = :u");
$STH->bindParam(':u', $json['u']); // Example only
try {
    $STH->execute();
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Now, I know that $STH will only contain one row, but I always do this:

```
foreach($STH as $row){
    ... $row['email']... etc
```

The `foreach` is utterly unnecessary and makes the code harder to follow. How can I access `email` in `$STH` without using `foreach`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
$row = $STH->fetch();
echo $row['email'];
```

It will get only 1 row.

Comment: `$row = $STH->fetch();` would also be fine as `$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` has already been defined.

Comment: Or even just `echo $STH->fetchColumn();`.

Answer (score 2):

Just fetch the first row using

```
$row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['email'];
```

Should do your trick

Comment: Or even just `echo $STH->fetchColumn();`.